# Inheritance and Composition relationship from same entities

Tags: vb.net, design-patterns

Is there anything against doing something like this:

```
Public Class clsLocation

        Inherits clsEntity
    End Class

    Public Class clsPerson
        Inherits clsEntity
    End Class

    Public Class clsEntity

    End Class

    Public Class clsEvent
        Inherits clsEntity

        Private persons() As clsPerson
        Private locations() As clsLocation        
    End Class
```

A Location is a Entity and a Person is a Entity (there are functions in clsEntity that are overridden in clsPerson and clsLocation).  Events have one or many persons and events have one or many locations.

I have not seen this done before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't see any cons to have a class architecture like the one you have, though i would use an abstract class for clsEntity (if you never need to instanciate it) and not prefix classes name with "cls".

I would have first asked myself, why wouldn't you have only 1 array in Event class since they're inheriting the same class (i.e. `Private entities() as clsEntity`) but actually it all depends on your business logic, if your Event have 2 clearly distinct relations having different meanings, then just keep it this way.

PS. There is a dedicated stackexchange for code review you may rather use for this kind of questions : https://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: clsEntity is actually an Abstract class.  I use 'cls' because this is what the previous developer did (for consistency).  Do you know any patterns that suggest this? Alternatively do you know if this pattern is implemented anywhere in the .NET framework.  +1.

Comment: There is no design pattern i know of for that kind of class architecture. It's just UML specification for the class diagram. Some Normal Form exist (they were taken from Merise to UML) and you can, if you want to, respect any of them for your whole class diagram. (googling "UML Normal Form" should give you enough results)